# Disks not mounting (10.10.5)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, mount, sd-card

Having an issue where multiple drives (External HD's via USB and an SD card inserted directly) will no longer mount when plugged in. If I open Disk Utility I can see the drive listed but the volume it contains is greyed out since it is not mounted. I can then click on the volume and mount it with Disk Utility. It then shows up in Finder, etc. and is completely usable. I have no idea why I suddenly have to do this, disks and the SD card slot always mounted just fine before.

Comment: Try remounting the drives and see if the problem persists. If not, I see a workaround that I would introduce in an answer

Comment: Sorry for not getting back on this. The problem doesn't go away after remounting.

Comment: Would it be OK if you had a script (let's say assigned to a shortcut) that would automatically mount the drive upon inserting it?

Comment: While I guess that's nice, it's not much different than my opening disk utility (one action using Spotlight) and then clicking mount... Seems like a USB/SD should just mount, it's a pretty basic thing!